# VB .NET, how to view address of variable in visual studio debug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, memory-address

When coding C#, in Debug mode, I use Watch Windows. Putting a "&" character in front of the variable will display it's address.
How can I do the same in VB .NET?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't get the address of a variable in VB.NET. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Well, I am learning programming, this just a way I come up with to determine whether my variables have been passed with byval or byref.

Comment: You can always look at the function definition? It's ByVal unless it says ByRef. The caller does not choose which to use, it is always what it says in the function signature.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but you could try using `AddressOf variableName` in the watch window.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway AddressOf only works for functions